# CodeIgniter parameters - unable to load requested file

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, php-include

I have this controller:

```
class Work extends MY_Controller {
    public function assign($id) {
        //validation checks
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view("work/assign/" . $id);
        } else {
            //success
        }
    }
}
```

As well as a view at `views/work/assign.php` I also have the following route:
`$route['work/assign/(:any)'] = 'work/assign/$1';`

When I go to `/work/assign/1` in my browser, and I get this error: `Unable to load the requested file: work/assign/1.php` I want it to render the page with the parameter 1

Comment: try using $this->load->view("work/assign/" . $id, '', true); see if it works for you.. this thought came from the topic "Returning views as data" at the following link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the wrong parameter in the `view` call

`$this->load->view("work/assign/" . $id);` since your last trailing slash tell CI that this is the `.php` and in your last trailing slash your `$id=1` so it searches to load the `1.php` the correct way to load the `view` and pass your id to view is make an array which contains the data you want to show in view then call view and pass the array, the array keys will converted to variables by CI

```
class Work extends MY_Controller {
    public function assign($id) {
        //validation checks
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['id']=$id;
            $this->load->view("work/assign" ,$data);
        } else {
            //success
        }
    }
}
```

In `assign.php` just echo `$id` and you will get desired id

Answer (score 1):

The loader doesn't care about your routes, and besides:

```
$route['work/assign/(:any)'] = 'work/assign/$1';
```

...doesn't do anything. This code:

```
$this->load->view("work/assign/" . $id);
```

...will always look for a file in `APPPATH/views/work/assign/$id.php` which I assume does not exist.

You want to use the second paramter in `view()` to load variables, for example:

```
$this->load->view("work/assign", array('id' => $id));
```

This will load the view file `work/assign.php` and import the variable `$id`.